# How to reference a column's query value vs stored value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I apologize for the title, I couldn't find a good way to word my question. I'm very new to SQL.

Essentially, I'm creating this table (the ids actually reference the students table, but I've simplified it here):

```
CREATE TABLE followers (student_id        int not null,
                        followee_id       int not null,
                        followsback       boolean,
                        PRIMARY KEY(student_id, followee_id)
                        SET followsback = IF(SELECT from followers
                          WHERE student_id = followee_id AND 
                          followee_id = student_id, 1, 0)
```

My problem lies with the IF statement. Say I ran this INSERT query:

```
INSERT into followers(student_id, followee_id) values(001,002)
```

This is supposed to store that student 001 is following student 002.

I need to select the followee (002) and check if they are following the student (001) back. To do this, I need to check the followers table for a user with student_id = followee_id (e.g student_id = 002), then check to see if that user (002) is following the original student_id (001).

The problem is that I don't know how to reference the student_id as specified within the INSERT query vs referencing the value within my SELECT query.

Then if the two students are following each other then I need to set followsback to 1.

Hopefully this makes sense, I am having a ridiculously hard time explaining this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no syntax in MySQL's CREATE TABLE statement to do what you show. It could be done by a rare feature in the SQL specification called an "assertion"—except there is no SQL database on the market that implements this feature.

You can try to implement it as a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER followback_ins BEFORE INSERT ON followers
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.followsback = EXISTS (
        SELECT * from followers
        WHERE student_id = NEW.followee_id AND followee_id = NEW.student_id);
```

But this has a problem. It only updates the followsback for the new record, not the original record.

```
mysql> insert into followers set student_id = 123, followee_id = 456;
mysql> insert into followers set student_id = 456, followee_id = 123;

mysql> select * from followers;
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| student_id | followee_id | followsback |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
|        123 |         456 |           0 |
|        456 |         123 |           1 |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

This is called an *anomaly* because when you try to store the same fact in two places, these two rows can contradict each other.

We could try to make a trigger that updates the original row too:

CREATE TRIGGER followback_ins AFTER INSERT ON followers
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE followers AS f1 JOIN followers AS f2 
    ON f1.student_id=f2.followee_id AND f1.followee_id=f2.student_id
  SET f1.followsback=true, f2.followsback=true;

But this is illegal. You can't update a table from a trigger on that same table (too much risk of infinite recursion).

```
ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'followers' in stored function/trigger
because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
function/trigger.
```

I'd suggest to forget about storing `followsback` at all. Instead, just store the following relationships as two rows, without a `followsback` column. If you want to know if they follow each other, you have to join two rows together:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM followers AS f1 JOIN followers AS f2 
  ON f1.student_id=f2.followee_id AND f1.followee_id=f2.student_id
WHERE f1.student_id = 123 AND f1.followee_id = 456.
```

This query will return 0 if there is no mutual following, and 2 if there is.